# Can I use the REST API for a site hosted on WordPress.com

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a blog hosted on WordPress.com. When I try to make a `GET` request to retrieve the posts I get a 'Not Found' html page.

https://alexkojin.wordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

I know about the [legacy public API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) but it doesn't allow me to retrieve private posts.

Can I use the REST API for site hosted on WordPress.com?

Comment: This question should be directed to the WordPress site maintainers.

Comment: Edited the question to help clarify the problem and solution

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On the WordPress.com platform the REST API is actually hosted and structured at https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2 **for all sites**. In addition, there's a `/sites/` endpoint that will namespace your specific site.

For example, the root endpoint for *your* site would be https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/alexkojin.wordpress.com/. The other endpoints behave the same way as they would on a self hosted platform.

For example, your pages would be found under https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/alexkojin.wordpress.com/pages

You can find more information at https://developer.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/wordpress-rest-api-on-wordpress-com/ including how to setup OAuth2 (which will be required to access private posts).