# WHEN DEPLOYING TO NETLIFY : TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined - Plugin gatsby-source-wordpress returned an error

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, netlify

I try to deploy my Gatsby/ wordpress site to netlify but keep having the same issue.

11:06:17 PM: Path: /wp-json
11:06:17 PM: The server response was "404 Not Found"
11:06:17 PM: error Plugin gatsby-source-wordpress returned an error
11:06:17 PM:
11:06:17 PM:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
11:06:17 PM:
11:06:17 PM:   - fetch.js:141 fetch
11:06:17 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/fetch.js:141:21
11:06:17 PM:
11:06:17 PM:   - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback

I tried to change my BaseURL but I still get the error.

My gatsby.config :

```
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime')
require('dotenv').config({
  path: '.env',
});
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/mameri`,
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `quentinmameri`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        /*
         * The base URL of the Wordpress site without the trailingslash and the protocol. This is required.
         * Example : 'gatsbyjsexamplewordpress.wordpress.com' or 'www.example-site.com'
         */
        baseUrl: "qmavocats.wordpress.com",
        // The protocol. This can be http or https.
        protocol: "https",
        // Indicates whether the site is hosted on wordpress.com.
        // If false, then the assumption is made that the site is self hosted.
        // If true, then the plugin will source its content on wordpress.com using the JSON REST API V2.
        // If your site is hosted on wordpress.org, then set this to false.
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        // If useACF is true, then the source plugin will try to import the Wordpress ACF Plugin contents.
        // This feature is untested for sites hosted on wordpress.com.
        // Defaults to true.
        useACF: true,

      }
    },




    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

I dont know why I have this error. Thank for your help.

Comment: Make sure `mywpsite.com/wp-json` is accessible. Gatsby fails to access it

Comment: indeed it is not accessible, but how do I make it accessible? thanks

Comment: I just checked and http://qmavocats.local/wp-json seems accesible

Comment: But this : https://qmavocats.wordpress.com/wp-json  doesnt exist

Comment: Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590975/5298150

Comment: You need to use: https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/qmavocats.wordpress.com address

Comment: ok I changed the base URL like this: this link : https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/qmavocats.wordpress.com/

Comment: the link "https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/qmavocats.wordpress.com/" works , but the link "https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/qmavocats.wordpress.com/wp-json" doesnt

Comment: with the "wp-json" extention it doesnt work. why should I do? thanks a lot for your help